# Bash - if statement combined with mail command

Tags: linux, bash, email, if-statement

I need to write a 1 liner which will ping a server and will send an email when there's no response. I wrote this so far

```
subject=$"Host_down" ;
i=$(ping -c1 -w3 100.100.100.100 | grep 100%) ;
j=$(echo $i | wc -l) ;
if [ $j -eq 1 ] ; then mail -s $subject admin@example.com < file.txt ; fi
```

but it sends email in both cases when if statement is either true or false. When I put "echo $i" instead of "mail..." like that

```
subject=$"Host_down" ;
i=$(ping -c1 -w3 100.100.100.100 | grep 100%) ;
j=$(echo $i | wc -l) ;
if [ $j -eq 1 ] ; then echo $i ; fi
```

then the if statement works fine and outputs $i when the server is down only.

I tried this as well

```
subject=$"Host_down" ;
i=$(ping -c1 -w3 100.100.100.100 | grep 100%) ;
j=$(echo $i | wc -l) ;
if [ $j -eq 1 ] ; then echo $i | mail -s $subject admin@example.com ; fi
```

and in this case also emails are sent when if gives true or false. I know programming a bit but I'm beginner in bash. Any advice on what I am doing wrong will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to write a 1 liner which will ping a server and will send an
>   email when there's no response.

You seem to have complicated things.  Simply check for the `ping` status:

```
subject="Host_down";
if ! ping -c1 -w3 100.100.100.100; then
  mail -s $subject admin@example.com < file.txt;
fi
```

The `mail` command would be executed if `ping` returns with a non-zero exit code.

---

EDIT: As [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21799136/bash-if-statement-combined-with-mail-command/21799270?noredirect=1#comment32987171_21799270) by [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner), a double-quoted string preceded by a dollar-sign (`$`) would cause the string to be [translated according to the current locale](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Locale-Translation.html).  So you probably wanted to say:

```
subject="Host_down"
```

instead of saying

```
subject=$"Host_down"
```

Comment: Not relevant, but note that the `$` in the assignment to `subject` is probably not necessary (unless you are intentionally using locale-based translation).

Comment: @chepner copy-paste effect!

Comment: I know :) I should have explicitly addressed the OP, or better yet, commented on the question and not your answer (+1, by the way).

Comment: @chepner I've updated the answer now to make your observation apparent to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with:

```
j=$(echo $i | wc -l) ;
```

It should read:

```
j=$(echo -n $i | wc -l) ;
```

The `-n` suppresses the newline that `echo` puts even when `$i` is blank. So now `wc -l` will correctly return `0` rather than `1`.

Your "working" version, where you say "the `if` statement works fine and outputs `$i` when the server is down only" probably *doesn't* work: when the server is up, a blank line is printed.